# Powershell 5 classes and singleton

Tags: powershell

Is there a correct/best/any way to make a singleton class using the class constructs in PowerShell 5.0?  I've tried something like this:

```
class ScannerGeometry
{
    [int] $EEprom;              # read eeprom
    # ....

    ScannerGeometry()
    {
        # ... fetch calibration from instrument
    }

    [ScannerGeometry] Instance() {
        if ($this -eq $null)
        {
            $this = [ScannerGeometry]::new()
        }
        return $this
    }
}
```

And assigning it with something like:

```
$scanner = [ScannerGeometry]::Instance()
```

Alas, I receive a runtime error of `Method invocation failed because [ScannerGeometry] does not contain a method named 'Instance'.`

Also, may one make the constructor(or any other method) private in PS5 classes?

Comment: huh, been skimming through 'get-help about_Classes -Full' earlier today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is visible like this since it is not static:

```
[ScannerGeometry]::new() | set x
PS C:\Work> $x | gm


   TypeName: ScannerGeometry

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
Instance    Method     ScannerGeometry Instance()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
EEprom      Property   int EEprom {get;set;}
```

You need to use keyword `static`. In that case `$this` is invalid so you have to change code a bit. Here is the code:

```
class ScannerGeometry
{
    [int] $EEprom;              # read eeprom


    static [ScannerGeometry] Instance() {
          return [ScannerGeometry]::new()
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Ok, here is the working code:

```
class ScannerGeometry
{
    [int] $EEprom              # read eeprom

    static [ScannerGeometry] $instance


    static [ScannerGeometry] GetInstance() {
          if ([ScannerGeometry]::instance -eq $null) { [ScannerGeometry]::instance = [ScannerGeometry]::new() }
          return [ScannerGeometry]::instance
    }
}

$s = [ScannerGeometry]::GetInstance()
```

Comment: helpful, but I get a new/different instance with each call to  `[ScannerGeometry] Instance()` not a singleton behavior.  I can use a external variable $Global:scannerObject = [ScannerGeometry]::new()` but that seems ... dirty?

Comment: guys, forgive my ignorance but how, why would you wanna to, instantiate a 'singleton'?

Comment: Yes, that's good.  It was my assumption that PowerShell did not allow for static variables in its classes.  Are they also allowed in standard functions?  Did the use of static change over the versions?  Thanks.

Comment: Jaqueline - in my case I only need to fetch the calibration data once but I might use it several  places.  Often resources like a serial port that has been opened is done as a singleton - open and setup on first use, there after just return the reference.

Comment: my vague understanding, in my utter coding n00bishnes, is that posh classes are more about types

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
class ScannerGeometry
{
    [int] $EEprom;              # read eeprom
    # ....

    ScannerGeometry()
    {
        # ... fetch calibration from instrument
    }

    [ScannerGeometry] Instance() {
        if ($this -eq $null)
        {
            $this = [ScannerGeometry]::new()
        }
        return $this
    }
}

$scangeo = [ScannerGeometry]::new().Instance()
```

PS : the code only gives no error, I'm completely clueless about the singleton context :(

[Source : HSGB](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/04/adding-methods-to-a-powershell-5-class/)

Comment: If you make the function static you loose the ability to reference $this.  Without making static you cannot call the method until you call instantiate the class.  What you want is an ability to not call new each time you need to reference the class - i.e. a singleton.

Comment: hm, 'not call new each time you need to reference the class', could you elaborate?